# Action для form на PHP

Tags: php

Есть форма отзыва с простой каптчей

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']){
    if($_POST['res'] == $_SESSION['res']){

    }else{
        $_SESSION['mes'] = '<p>Дан неверный ответ!</p>';
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}

$a = rand(1,10);
$b = rand(1,10);
$_SESSION['res'] = $a + $b;
?>


<form action="vidguki-form-result.php" method="post" id="form-vidguki">
<input name="author" placeholder="ВАШЕ ІМ'Я" class="form-name" maxlength="34" onkeypress="return isNotMax(event)" required /><br>
<textarea name="text" placeholder="ВАШ ВІДГУК" class="form-message" maxlength="500" onkeypress="return isNotMax(event)" required></textarea><br>
<?php echo $a. ' + ' .$b. ' = ';?><input type="text" name="res" />
<input name="submit" class="form-btn" type="submit" value="НАПИСАТИ ВІДГУК " />
</form>

<?php
echo $_SESSION['mes'];
unset($_SESSION['mes']);
?>
```

Как правильно написать action в блоке условия при проверки каптчи?
В случае если каптча правильная надо передать данные в vidguki-form-result.php
Если же не верная, то вывести сообщения на этой странице

vidguki-form-result.php:

```
include ("block/db.php");

if (isset($_POST['author'])) {$author = $_POST['author']; if ($author == '') {$author='Аноним';}}
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text = $_POST['text']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}

?>

<div id="content-index">
    <div id="name-menu">
        <?php
        if (isset($author) && isset($text))
        {
            $resultaddvidguk = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vidguki (author,text) VALUES ('$author','$text')");
            if ($resultaddvidguk == 'true') {echo "<h3>ДЯКУЄМО ЗА ВАШУ ДУМКУ ! ВАШ ВІДГУК ДУЖЕ ВАЖЛИВИЙ ДЛЯ НАС !</h3>";}
            else {echo "<h3>ПОМИЛКА ! ВІДГУК НЕ БУВ ДОДАНИЙ !</h3>";}
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h3>ВИ ЗАПОВНИЛИ НЕ ВСІ ПОЛЯ ТОМУ ВІДГУК НЕ БУВ ОПУБЛІКОВАН !</h3>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="vidguk-btn-nazad">
        <p><a href="vidguki.php">ПОВЕРНУТИСЯ ДО ВІДГУКІВ</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST['submit']){
    if($_POST['res'] == $_SESSION['res']){
        include ("block/db.php");
        if (isset($_POST['author'])) {$author = $_POST['author']; if ($author == '') {$author='Аноним';}}
        if (isset($_POST['text'])) {$text = $_POST['text']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}?>
        <div id="content-index">
            <div id="name-menu">
                <?
                if (isset($author) && isset($text))
                {
                    $resultaddvidguk = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO vidguki (author,text) VALUES ('$author','$text')");
                    if ($resultaddvidguk == 'true') {
                        echo "<h3>ДЯКУЄМО ЗА ВАШУ ДУМКУ ! ВАШ ВІДГУК ДУЖЕ ВАЖЛИВИЙ ДЛЯ НАС !</h3>";
                    }else{
                        echo "<h3>ПОМИЛКА ! ВІДГУК НЕ БУВ ДОДАНИЙ !</h3>";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<h3>ВИ ЗАПОВНИЛИ НЕ ВСІ ПОЛЯ ТОМУ ВІДГУК НЕ БУВ ОПУБЛІКОВАН !</h3>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div id="vidguk-btn-nazad">
                <p><a href="vidguki.php">ПОВЕРНУТИСЯ ДО ВІДГУКІВ</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?}else{
        $_SESSION['mes'] = '<p>Дан неверный ответ!</p>';
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}else{
    $a = rand(1,10);
    $b = rand(1,10);
    $_SESSION['res'] = $a + $b;?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="form-vidguki">
    <input name="author" placeholder="ВАШЕ ІМ'Я" class="form-name" maxlength="34" onkeypress="return isNotMax(event)" required /><br>
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="ВАШ ВІДГУК" class="form-message" maxlength="500" onkeypress="return isNotMax(event)" required></textarea><br>
    <?php echo $a. ' + ' .$b. ' = ';?><input type="text" name="res" />
    <input name="submit" class="form-btn" type="submit" value="НАПИСАТИ ВІДГУК " />
    </form>
<?}
echo $_SESSION['mes'];
unset($_SESSION['mes']);
?>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45942/discussion-on-answer-by-webdev-action--form--php).